# C# custom app.config with multiple data types

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I'm a newbie c# programmer.

I searched for a lot of tutorial related to app.config, but I couldn't find what I'm looking for. I planned to use it as a replacement for database, because my data is just little.

How do you create a config file with more than one category. is it legal to do this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<Codes>
<Code value="00">Success</Code>
<Code value="01">Try Again</Code>
<Code value="02">Invalid Format</Code>
...
</Codes>

<Fields>
<Field type="1">0034</Field>
<Field type="2">Food</Field>
... 
</Fields>
</configuration>
```

And if this is possible. Will there be changes on how to parse it?

Comment: The app.config file is not, and should not be used as a database. It's a configuration file that typically is located in a place where a regular user does not have write access. You will be a lot better off just creating a regular xml file or something like that.

Comment: I thought of that too, but I was worried about how to generate it if it doesn't existed yet. Is there a better way to generate xml files?

Comment: A Property within the configuration file cannot have multiple values.  You should use your own xml file, the configuration file is no an option, at least for your planned implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, it's possible and easy. You can write your own custom config section handler ([ConfigurationSection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationsection.aspx)).

Take a look at this articles:

- [How to: Create Custom Configuration Sections Using ConfigurationSection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx)
- [Understanding Section Handlers - App.config File](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ConfigSections.aspx)
- [Creating a Custom Configuration Section in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/CustomConfigurationSectio.aspx)
- [Custom Configuration Section in C#](http://nnish.com/2009/09/17/custom-configuration-section-in-c/)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you actually want to use just plain old XML instead of trying to push it in to the config.  Is there any reason you are trying to store data in a config file?  Because by it's very nature data is different that configuration in most cases.

My recommendation is to store your data in to an XML file and then use the XmlDocument object to parse through the data.  I am probably also going to be yelled at from the POCO purists, but you can also use DataSets and DataTables to read/store the XML data, that way you don't have to manage the XML your self.

Comment: My friend saw me using xml and suggested to me that app.config would be better, but since I'm just still new to c#, I checked it anyways. I guess xml would still be the way to go. By the way, do you have any links related to using DataSets and DataTables for XML. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The app.config file follows a pre defined schema. You can extend it using config sections but using it for application data would be incorrect in my opinion.

You could certainly use plain old XML to store that data though. Google around for LINQ to XML and C# + xml and you'll find lots and lots of information.